# Filling array with 'zeroes' -memset() does not work-

Tags: c, arrays, memset

This is the code

```
int x, y, n, i, j, l, m, o;
printf ("podaj szerokosc planszy na jakiej chcesz zagrac\n");
scanf ("%d", &x);
printf ("podaj dlugosc planszy na jakiej chcesz zagrac\n");
scanf ("%d", &y);
int plansza [x][y];
memset(plansza, 0, sizeof plansza);
int plansza2 [x][y];
memset(plansza2, 0, sizeof plansza2);

printf("plansza: \n");
for(j=0;j<x;j++)
{
    for(l=0;l<y;l++)
    {
        printf("%d",plansza[x][y]);
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("plansza2: \n");
for(m=0;m<x;m++)
{
    for(o=0;o<y;o++)
    {
        printf("%d",plansza2[x][y]);
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And this is the result:
[image: Result]

Don't know why `memset()` doesn't work at all and I completaly dont know why. What should I do to fill the array all with zeroes?

Comment: What are `j`, `l`, `m`, and `o` for?

Comment: sizeof wont work like you think it will, it will return the size of the pointer that represents the array, not the length of the array.

Comment: @Ben: `sizeof` yields the total size of the array (not the number of elements in the array and not the size of a pointer).

Comment: @Ben: That's an array. No pointer decay occurred. Arrays are not pointers, even though there is an implicit conversion to pointer.

Comment: Next time indent better.

Comment: I guarantee you; `memset` works.

Comment: Also be aware that your code is using variable length arrays which are a C99 feature not supported by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `x` and `y` as indexes within your print loops despite the fact that they're not the variables actually *controlling* those loops.

In the first print loop, you use `j` and `l` as the control variables, and `m` and `o` in the second print loop. You need to index the array with whatever control variables you're using rather than `x` and `y`, which are the dimensions.

Let's say you entered `5` and `7` for the dimensions. This gives you elements from `arr[0][0]` through to `arr[4][6]` inclusive. Because you are using the *dimensions* to access the elements within the print loops, you will always get `arr[5][7]` which is actually outside the bounds of the array. Thats likely to just give you a value well beyond the end of the array (and the *same* value due to the unchanging indexes), though technically, it's undefined behaviour so it could do *anything.*

Once you start using the correct indexes I think you'll find `memset` works just fine.

Comment: `int plansza [x][y];memset(plansza, 0, sizeof plansza);int plansza2 [x][y];memset(plansza2, 0, sizeof plansza2);
printf("plansza: \n"); for(j=0;j<x;j++)
    {
        for(l=0;l<y;l++)
                    {printf("%d",plansza[j][l]);
                    printf(" ");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
    }

     printf("plansza2: \n");
    for(j=0;j<x;j++)
    {
                    for(l=0;l<y;l++)
                    {printf("%d",plansza2[j][l]);
                    printf(" ");
                    }
                    printf("\n"); }` Is it correct now?